# Terraform aws_iam_policy_document datasource, statement and conditions question

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I am trying to create aws_iam_policy_document datasource with statement that depends on two variables. If variable serviceaccount (string) is not defined (empty) skip statement, if lenght of variable serviceaccounts (list) skip statement.

```
statement {
    actions = [
      "sts:AssumeRole",
    ]

    principals {
      type = "Federated"

      identifiers = [
        local.eks_oidc_provider_arn,
      ]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "${local.eks_oidc_issuer_url}:sub"

      values = [
        "system:serviceaccount:${var.namespace}:${var.serviceaccount}",
      ]
    }

    condition {
      test     = "StringEquals"
      variable = "${local.eks_oidc_issuer_url}:aud"

      values = [
        "sts.amazonaws.com",
      ]
    }
  }
```

This would be the statement that needs adjusting but not sure how. I tried using ChatGPT but not much success. This is a TF module statement so there will always be defined one or another variable. Probably I could replace serviceaccount with just serviceaccounts and just pass list of elements, but I wanted to make module backwards compatible. The key is to iterate over list values in `"system:serviceaccount:${var.namespace}:${var.serviceaccount}"` so if there are two elements in list there will be two lines of values.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out. In locals crated `condition_values = [ for account in var.serviceaccount != null ? [var.serviceaccount] : var.serviceaccounts : "system:serviceaccount:${var.namespace}:${account}" ]`  and then passed `locals.condition_values` to values in condition. The key was to prepare data outside datasource and just use data in it.